# RSYNC copies nothing when using option --include=file

Tags: rsync

I want to copy part of a source to a destination:

```
SRC_DIR=/a/b/c/d/e  
DEST_DIR=/x/y/z/d/e
```

When my script starts, I create all the folders in `$DEST_DIR`:

```
mkdir -pv /x/y/z/d/e
```

I have a list of relative paths from source
which are the first child of `e` that I want to copy. 
This list is built from the output of a find command and looks like:

```
/USER_CONFIG_COPY/G731GV/REAL/2023_06_17_22h11/user_install/root  
....  
....  
/002_DATA/SSH/2023_09_01.prev/root  
....   
....   
....  
/002_DATA/USER_CONFIG_INITIAL/root  
....   
....  
....  
....  
/001_SCRIPTS/000_TOOLS/root  
....   
....
```

To build the Include list, I first put the parent's folder,
then the list obtained from the find output. 
So the list looks like this:

```
/a  
/a/b  
/a/b/c  
/a/b/c/d  
/a/b/c/d/e  
/USER_CONFIG_COPY/G731GV/REAL/2023_06_17_22h11/user_install/root  
....  
....  
/002_DATA/SSH/2023_09_01.prev/root  
....
```

The final command is:

```
rsync -arzh -vvv --include='/tmp/000_my_include_root_dirlist.txt' --exclude='*' "$SRC_DIR/"  "$DST_DIR/"
```

I have tried many tips found on U&L Stack Exchange with no success. 
What am I doing wrong?

Ok Chris suggestion works on a small set of folders. My problem come from a missing --recursive option and a problem using sticky bit on the folders. I am going to do a full test. I give news asap.

Comment: I find your question confusing. (1) Are `USER_CONFIG_COPY`, `002_DATA` and `001_SCRIPTS` subdirectories of `e`?  If so, you should not put `/` in front of them (e.g., `/USER_CONFIG_COPY`).  (1a) `find` outputs `./USER_CONFIG_COPY`.  The **`.`** is not decoration; you cannot just leave it off.  (2) If you want to reference `/a/b/c/d/e/USER_CONFIG_COPY/...`, it is not correct to put `/a/b/c/d/e` on one line and `/USER_CONFIG_COPY/...` on the next.  Each line must be a valid filename.

Comment: As said in may question YES : 'I have a list of relative paths from source which are the first child of e that I want to copy.'

Comment: You shouldn't be missing a recursive option - it's included in the `-a` (`--archive`) flag I gave in my answer. However, if you use `include-from` then recursion is intentionally disabled. You should _explain what you are trying to achieve_.

Comment: @Chris your suggestion works on a small set of folders and on a real set of data after adding the missing option --recursive . Thank you very much for helping and for your patience. Thread is closed.

Comment: @jcdole if one of the answers best helped you please remember to accept it with the ✔ alongside

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your option `--include='/tmp/000_my_include_root_dirlist.txt'` includes the file `"$SRC_DIR/tmp/000_my_include_root_dirlist.txt"`, not its contents. You probably want `--files-from` and neither `--include` nor `--exclude`:

```
rsync --dry-run -ah -vv --files-from='/tmp/000_my_include_root_dirlist.txt' "$SRC_DIR/"  "$DST_DIR"
```

Now remove the first set of `/a` through to `/a/b/c/d/e` from your list of files and ensure the remainder of the listed files have paths relative to `$SRC_DIR`, one per line. For example `/my_file.txt` to represent `"$SRC_DIR/my_file.txt"`.

I've added `--dry-run` so that `rsync` will only show you what it's going to do. Remove that option when you're ready for it execute. I've also removed the redundant `-r` as it's part of `-a`, and `-z` because it's pointless when copying locally.

I'm also a little puzzled why you seem to want to generate a list of files to be copied when `rsync` can do that itself. (Perhaps you've got some other criteria applied to `find` that restricts the set of files?)

Comment: # make a list with relative path to  "$SRC_DIR/"
find "$SRC_DIR/" -type d -name 'root' | sed 's#^'$PATH_INCLUDE_FROM'##' >> "$TMP2"  I don't know how to make that directly with rsync

Comment: @jcdole in your question please

Comment: Although that does just look like a full set of files, in which case I'd have to ask why you are bothering with a specific set and include/exclude options at all. Rsync does all this directly and easily

Comment: After reading the all the examples I found, what I incorrectly understood then was that the 'include' list must be relative to the source path, and that we had to add all the parents ( in my case/a/b/cd/e ) at top of list. I do not want to copy the entire source ( in my case "/a") but only the part that starts at "/a/b/c/d/e/" and which contains only repertories whose name is "root".

Comment: Following your advice, here is the command I use: 
rsync  -ah -vvv --files-from=/tmp/000_my_include_root_dirlist_tmp3.txt "/run/media/user_install/INS_STEP2_MINI/NEW_INSTALL_LINUX_2023/2024_02_01_19h00/MY_PROJECTS/MY_INSTALL_STEP_1/2024_02_01_19h00/"  "/run/media/user_install/sandisk_0_16GO/NEW_INSTALL_LINUX_2023/2024_02_01_19h00/MY_PROJECTS/MY_INSTALL_STEP_1/2024_02_01_19h00"

Comment: All repertories are created on the destination, but no files are copied. Using the "Files-from=" option, would it miss an option to request that the files be copied as well.

Thank you for helping.

Comment: "_the 'include' list must be relative to the source path_" - that is correct. Please [edit your question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/771078/edit) to provide the additional information, and those who've answered can then choose to amend their answers to handle the new detail, and other people may be able to add new answers

Answer (score 0):

If, as you say, `USER_CONFIG_COPY`, `002_DATA` and `001_SCRIPTS`
are subdirectories of `e`,
then you should not put `/` in front of them (e.g., `/USER_CONFIG_COPY`). 
“`/USER_CONFIG_COPY`” indicates a `USER_CONFIG_COPY` directory
in the *root* directory.

If you `cd` to `/a/b/c/d/e` and run `find`,
you will get output that looks like

```
./USER_CONFIG_COPY/G731GV/REAL/2023_06_17_22h11/user_install/root
    ︙
    ︙
    ︙
./002_DATA/SSH/2023_09_01.prev/root
    ︙
    ︙
    ︙
```

The **`.`**s at the beginning are not decoration;
you cannot just leave them off. 
They indicate that the paths are relative to **`.`**,
the current directory (which is `/a/b/c/d/e`).

Likewise, if you run `find "$SRC_DIR/" criteria`,
you will get output that looks like

```
/a/b/c/d/e/USER_CONFIG_COPY/G731GV/REAL/2023_06_17_22h11/user_install/root
    ︙
    ︙
    ︙
/a/b/c/d/e/002_DATA/SSH/2023_09_01.prev/root
    ︙
    ︙
    ︙
```

If you pipe that through `sed 's#^'$PATH_INCLUDE_FROM'##'`,
assuming `$PATH_INCLUDE_FROM` is `/a/b/c/d/e`,
then you will also get the output that you showed. 
And it’s equally wrong. 
If you want to reference `/a/b/c/d/e/USER_CONFIG_COPY/...`,
it is not correct to put `/a/b/c/d/e` on one line
and `/USER_CONFIG_COPY/...` on the next. 
Each line must be a valid filename.

By the way,

- Why do you have two variables (`SRC_DIR` and `PATH_INCLUDE_FROM`)
  to refer to the same directory?
- `'s#^'$PATH_INCLUDE_FROM'##'` is bad syntax. 
  Use `"s#^$PATH_INCLUDE_FROM##"` (with double quotes, `"`) instead.

Comment: After reading many examples, what I incorrectly understood then was that the 'include' list must be relative to the source path, and that we had to add all the parents ( in my case  /a/b/cd/e ) at top of list. So 
After reading many examples, what I incorrectly understood then was that the 'include' list must be relative to the source path, and that we had to add all the parents ( in my case  /a/b/cd/e ) at top of list. So 
/a
/a/b
/a/b/c
/a/b/c/d
/a/b/c/d/e
is added to force rsync to parse from top, else nothing should be found.

Comment: This is why all element in the list are relative to the source and start like this :
    /000_DIVERS/NOT_IN_USE/002_DATA/USER_CONFIG/root
    /USER_CONFIG_COPY/G731GV/REAL/2023_06_17_22h11/user_install/root
    /USER_CONFIG_COPY/G731GV/REAL/2023_06_17_22h11/root
    /USER_CONFIG_COPY/G731GV/VM/LEAP_15.4_VM_0_TEST_MINI_INSTALL/2023_09_23_23h18/root
    /002_DATA/SSH/2023_09_14.prev/root
    /002_DATA/SSH/2023_09_16/REAL_VM_ROOT/root
    
This what I had understood

Comment: I use a variable "PATH_INCLUDE_FROM" because I find it more comfortable; it simplifies my understanding when reading my script.
Thank you for helping